# Mean difference between four groups with

Tags: regression, mean, residuals, skewness

I have four categorical groups (A, B, C, D) each with one mean representing a numerical, skewed variable. The data structure is as follows:

```
Rows: 4
Columns: 2
$ complexity <dbl> 26.64353107, -57.49406460, -40.99757998, 71.84811350
$ CEFR       <fct> A1, A2, B1, B2
```

Problem: Unfortunately, the full data points per group are unusable due to statistical reasons (they are heavily influenced by another factor). Thus, I had to use the mean which is derived from the residuals of linear regression to reduce the influence of the unwanted factor.

Question: Can I run a statistical test to measure the mean difference between the 4 groups even when each group has only 1 observation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the reason why exactly you can only use that mean, but let's just focus on the problem that you just have 4 numbers and want to see the difference between those 4. If you want 2-by-2 comparisons, you can just take the difference of those means, if you want an overall difference, you just calculate the mean of those means. Now the main point of concern to me is the precision of those estimates. You can't really test a difference between 2 numbers (with for example a t-test) if you don't know anything about the precision of those 2 numbers.

So, if you also have the variance of those means and you know how many subjects are used to get it, than I see no problem in using a t-test or ANOVA.

If you are planning to do multiple t-tests, don't forget to account for a multiplicity correction as well.

(Note: this is when all distributional assumptions are valid, otherwise you will have to look at non-parametric alternatives like Wilcoxon (signed) rank sum test or Kruskal-Wallis tests, or maybe other tests that take your design better into account).

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! Much appreciated!

Comment: I was able to conduct a statistical test on those 4 data points by including how many subjects were used to get each point. Each point was an aggregate of 1000 subjects (observations/iterations). Thus, each unique point was repeated 1000 times. A Krsukal-Wallis test was used since the data was not normally distributed. The Krsukal-Wallis test generated results after including the number of subjects (versus NA when not including N subjects). Thank you, Wouter!

Comment: Great! You include some notion of variability right? Not just 1000 times the same observation? Glad that I could help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have data about the variability of the means. I had to follow previous codes to generate the current data. So, it seems I don't have much choice. I might not report the statistical results and stick only with the means as they are. Many thanks for your time and your very helpful replies!:)